# Add image to navigation

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, hottowel

Im using the hot towel template and I would like to add a different image for each navigation route. How would i accomplish this? At the moment its just using the same image.

Here is my code for routing

```
     function boot() {
        router.mapNav('home');
        router.mapNav('details');
        router.mapNav('myPage');

        log('Hot Towel SPA Loaded!', null, true);
        return router.activate('home');
    }
```

Knockout code

```
   <div id="frame">
        <ul class="project-list" data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
            <li data-bind="css: { current: isActive }"><a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }" class=""
                href="#"><span class="image"><i class="icon-desktop"></i></span><span class="title"
                    data-bind="text:name"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mapNav` other overload which takes an object as the first argument where you can add custom properties like:

```
router.mapNav({url: 'myPage', image: 'icon-desktop'});
router.mapNav({url: 'myPage', image: 'icon-something'});
router.mapNav({url: 'myPage', image: 'icon-somethingelse'});
```

And in your view you can just write:

```
<span class="image">
   <i data-bind="css: image"></i>
</span>
```

Or if you want to specify real image urls you can also do that:

```
router.mapNav({url: 'myPage', imageUrl: 'http://server.com/myimage.png'});

<span class="image">
   <img data-bind="attr: { scr: imageUrl }"></i>
</span>
```

Alternativly to avoid conflicts with durandal's own properties you can put your custom settings on a `settings` object

```
router.mapNav({url: 'myPage', { settings: { image: 'icon-desktop'}});
```

And in your view:

```
<span class="image">
   <i data-bind="css: settings.image"></i>
</span>
```